# Rspec Test on Controller w/Namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have an 'Api' namespace I'm using and I want to write a test for my controller. However, I can't get the post method to work for this.

I've tried

```
describe Api::EnvsController do

    describe "POST create" do
        it "creates a new env" do
            expect { post :create, :env => { :name => "This_te" } }.to change(Env,:count).by(1)
        end
    end
end



describe EnvsController do

    describe "POST create" do
        it "creates a new env" do
            expect { post :create, :env => {:name => "mym"} }.to change(Env,:count).by(1) 
        end
    end
end
```

Error:

```
  4) Api::EnvsController POST create creates a new env
     Failure/Error: expect { post :create, :env => {:name => "mym"} }.to change(Env,:count).by(1)
     ActionController::UnknownFormat:
       ActionController::UnknownFormat
     # ./app/controllers/api/envs_controller.rb:5:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/api/envs_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/api/envs_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) EnvsController POST create creates a new env
     Failure/Error: expect { post :create, :env => {:name => "mym"} }.to change(Env,:count).by(1)
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:env=>{:name=>"mym"}, :controller=>"envs", :action=>"create"}
     # ./spec/controllers/envs_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/envs_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Which leads me to believe that 'post :create, :env => :name => "string" }...' isn't working appropriately. Though I've tried every derivation I can think of based off of RSpec's post method, sample here.

```
post "/widgets", :widget => {:name => "My Widget"}
```

When I change this to suit my needs

```
expect { post "api/envs", :env => { :name => "This_te" } }.to change(Env,:count).by(1)
```

I receive a url generation error saying that I don't have a route that matches it. IE

```
  5) Api::EnvsController POST create creates a new env
     Failure/Error: expect { post "/api/envs", :env => { :name => "This_te" } }.to change(Env,:count).by(1)
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:env=>{:name=>"This_te"}, :controller=>"api/envs", :action=>"/api/envs"}
     # ./spec/controllers/api/envs_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/api/envs_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Create from controller as requested.

```
  def create
    @env = Env.new(env_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @env.save
        format.json { render json: @env, status: :created }
      else
        format.json { render json: @env.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: For starters, the `expect` method is only available within the block of an `it` call.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this. Perhaps I should have posted the full code blocks, I tried to show the different method calls I've tried. Hence two describes to the same controller name. I'll make it a bit more obvious.

Comment: What output/error are you getting?

Comment: Added error and additional tests, removed capybara tag since this has nothing to do with capybara.

Comment: The spec code you've posted isn't even valid syntax (e.g. unbalanced `{}` in first `expect` call). Also, you should post your controller code's `create` method as that is where the error is coming from. Finally, did you not copy/paste your output? The double colons and initial apostrophe in `.rb::5 in 'create'` look like typos.

Comment: "ActionController:UnknownFormat:" looks like you would want to add `format: :json` to your API calls?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin I did not copy paste the output or the input, was working between two devices and wasn't able to access the internet on one. Hence the invalid syntax you're referencing.

Comment: @phoet I have the default format set to JSON in my routes, do I need to have it in the controller as well?

Comment: I'd suggest updating the question with the actual code/output, even if it involves transferring it to the submitting machine by sneakernet or taking a picture of the screen and posting an image. These problems are hard enough to solve without having to deal with transcription errors. But that's just me. Perhaps others are willing to work with the question as it stands.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin thanks for taking the time thus far. I have copy pasted the errors from terminal and from my editor.